# pulseaudio:"Denied access to client with invalid authentication data"

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I'm running Debian Stretch on a RPi 3 and to play audio via my bluetotth box without any luck. This is basically what I did:

https://github.com/davidedg/NAS-mod-config/blob/master/bt-sound/bt-sound-Bluez5_PulseAudio5.txt

My bluetooth box is connected, but I don't get any audio output, because of this error:

```
● pulseaudio.service - Pulse Audio
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-09-05 00:23:34 CEST; 19min ago
 Main PID: 336 (pulseaudio)
   CGroup: /system.slice/pulseaudio.service
           └─336 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit --disable-shm --exit-idle-time=-1

Sep 05 00:41:52 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:42:05 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:42:18 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:42:22 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:42:25 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:42:38 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:42:52 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:43:05 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:43:08 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
Sep 05 00:43:21 raspberrypi pulseaudio[336]: W: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Denied access to client with invalid authentication data.
```

What I tried to solve it:

The users (root, pi and mopidy) are in the groups pulse, pulse-access and audio

Added that line to `system.pa` `load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/my-pulse-socket-name` and added the file `~/.config/pulse/client.conf` with that content `default-server = unix:/tmp/my-pulse-socket-name`

If I start pulseaudio not as `--system` in usermode it is working without any issues.

Any hints?

Thanks in Advance - Configs are on GitHub, but I'm not allowed to post more than two links.

PulseAudio Log: https://gist.github.com/tringler/f88b227e99624ad990b836dda9de5507

Comment: Read through this post about Bluetooth A2DP and Raspberry Pi 3 and lets discuss after that, http://youness.net/raspberry-pi/bluetooth-headset-raspberry-pi-3-ad2p-hsp